# SQL server join unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have two unrelaled table:

PEOPLE table:

```
   ID | NAME | AGE
    ------------
   1  | DAVE | 43
   1  | ANNE | 25
   1  | MIKE | 58
```

PLACES table:

```
ID | COUNTRY | TOWN
------------------
1  |   USA    | WILMINGTON
1  |   GER    | BERLIN
1  |   POR    | LISBON
1  |   JPN    | KYOTO
```

I want a Result like this:

```
NAME | AGE | COUNTRY | TOWN
-----------------------------
ANNE |  25 | GER     | BERLIN
DAVE |  43 | JPN     | KYOTO
MIKE |  58 | POR     | LISBON
           | USA     | WILMINGTON
```

Comment: how do you know which row in people goes with the row in places?

Comment: I tried to use joins and union but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do ANNE and BERLIN have to appear in the same row? If not, you can use cross join with select distinct.

Comment: Yes they have to apear in the same row

Comment: You need to explain how you know ANNE and BERLIN belong together.

Comment: I agree with you @AaronBertrand. May be the OP want to join them via record number. hehe

Answer (score 4):

let me give this a try:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Name, '') Name,
       COALESCE(a.Age, '') Age,
       b.Country,
       b.Town
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name]) AS RowNum, Name, Age
     FROM   People) a Right Join 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Country]) AS RowNum, Country, Town
     FROM   Places) b ON a.RowNum = b.RowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

You need at least one piece of data in each table to join against. Typically this is handled with a Primary Key/Foreign Key relationship. You could create a primary key in your PLACES table (ex. 1=USA, 2=GER, 3=POR, 4=JPN) and then place foreign keys in a column of your PEOPLE table that match the appropriate place for each person (ex. 2=ANNE, 4=DAVE, 3=MIKE).

Answer (score 1):

I completely don't recommend this!!! but I found it a good challenge. I would highly recommend going with Sean's recommendation and do this with keys.

Anyway, this query will give you exactly what you asked for without changing your schema (it also assumes your data is exactly represented).

Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0486/8

```
Select Distinct
  case when town = 'Wilmington' Then NULL else Name end as Name, 
  case when town = 'Wilmington' Then NULL else Age end as Age,
  Country, 
  Town
FROM People, Places
Where 
     (Name = 'Anne' AND Town = 'Berlin')
  OR (Name = 'Dave' AND Town = 'Kyoto')
  OR (Name = 'Mike' AND Town = 'Lisbon')
  OR (Town = 'Wilmington')
Order By Country Asc
```

**EDIT**

To complete my answer and to provide a more appropriate solution, I recommend you add a PlaceID to both tables and then Left join on it.

Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5ee8/3

```
Create Table People(
  Name varchar(255),
  Age int,
  PlaceID int
)

Create Table Places(
  PlaceID int,
  Country varchar(255),
  Town varchar(255)
)

Insert Into People Values ('Dave', 43, 2)
Insert Into People Values ('Anne', 25, 1)
Insert Into People Values ('Mike', 58, 3)

Insert Into Places Values (1, 'Ger', 'Berlin')
Insert Into Places Values (2, 'Jpn', 'Kyoto')
Insert Into Places Values (3, 'Por', 'Lisbon')
Insert Into Places Values (4, 'USA', 'Wilmington')

Select 
  Name, Age, Country, Town 
FROM 
  Places
  Left Join People On Places.PlaceID = People.PlaceID
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want these joined on order by alphabetical, but this doesn't really make a lot of sense...

```
WITH x AS (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME) FROM People),
     y AS (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNTRY) FROM Places)
SELECT * FROM x FULL OUTER JOIN y ON x.rn = y.rn;
```

Comment: I want to joined and sort them by ID.

Comment: @Russel how is that possible? All of your ID values are 1.